# Extracting place details from JSON

Tags: android, json, google-places

I am having an issue here. In my **android application**, I have the location of the place, so relatively I want to get the type to which this place belongs to. So I found the solution in `"types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ]` but the problem is that I don't know how to extract each type from this JSONObject.
this is an example of something similar to what I want.

```
 URL googlePlaces = new URL(
                        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=" +URLEncoder.encode(args[0], "UTF-8")+"&sensor=true&key=key");
 URLConnection tc = googlePlaces.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    tc.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            //take Google's legible JSON and turn it into one big string.
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
                JSONObject predictions = new JSONObject(sb.toString()); 
 JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(predictions.getString("predictions"));
                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                     predictionsArr.add(jo.getString("description"));
                }
            }
```

Comment: Which JSON parser are you using?

Comment: excuse my lack of knowledge, but what do you mean by "which" JSON parser?

Comment: The code that iterates through the JSON file/string, so you may extract it and parse it properly.

Comment: this is an example of something similar 
'URL googlePlaces = new URL(
                        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=" +URLEncoder.encode(args[0], "UTF-8")+"&sensor=true&key=key");
                JSONObject predictions = new JSONObject(sb.toString()); 
 JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(predictions.getString("predictions"));
                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                     predictionsArr.add(jo.getString("description"));
                }
            }'

Comment: well edit that into the post, I can't understand any of that.

Comment: ok so it's edited now